# How do I make this merge dynamic in python?

Tags: python, logging, zip, python-logging

I have this code where I'm merging the content of a lot of .txt files into only one .txt file.
Those .txt files are generated according to a date (in this case 01-12-2022, but in the folder there are a lot of logs of other dates like 02-12-2022, 03-12-2022, it logs for 9 days), how do I make the merge with all the dates? And also make this dynamic, like when I get those logs in February for example, this works the same (merge all the logs from all the nine days into only one .txt file)

The code:

```
zip_file = r'C:\Users\Viniz\Downloads\devkmbe-5511001_05-12-2022_00_20_09.zip'
pastaLogs = 'devkmbe-5511001_05-12-2022_00_20_09'
audioCapture = pastaLogs + '/AudioCaptureMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt'
audioMatching = pastaLogs + '/AudioMatchingMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt'
audioWatermarking = pastaLogs + '/AudioWatermarkingMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt'
awmDetection = pastaLogs + '/AwmDetectionLog_01_12_2022.txt'
backendMemory = pastaLogs + '/BackendMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt'
batteryCharge = pastaLogs + '/BatteryChargeControlLog_01_12_2022.txt' #f6
batteryLife = pastaLogs + '/BatteryLifeMonitorLog_01_12_2022.txt'
bluetoothComms = pastaLogs + '/BluetoothCommsLog_01_12_2022.txt'
btrcLog = pastaLogs + '/BTRCLog_01_12_2022.txt'
dashboardCommunication = pastaLogs + '/DashBoard_Communication_01_12_2022.txt'
deliveryService = pastaLogs + '/DeliveryServiceMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt'
dmbeLog = pastaLogs + '/DMBELog_01_12_2022.txt'



with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    with zip_ref.open(audioCapture) as f1, zip_ref.open(audioMatching) as f2,zip_ref.open(audioWatermarking) as f3, zip_ref.open(awmDetection) as f4,zip_ref.open(backendMemory) as f5, zip_ref.open(batteryCharge) as f6,zip_ref.open(batteryLife) as f7,zip_ref.open(bluetoothComms) as f8,zip_ref.open(btrcLog) as f9, zip_ref.open(dashboardCommunication) as f10, zip_ref.open(deliveryService) as f11 :
        primeiroLog = f1.read()
        segundoLog = f2.read()
        terceiroLog = f3.read()
        quartoLog = f4.read()
        quintoLog= f5.read()
        sextoLog = f6.read()
        setimoLog = f7.read()
        oitavoLog = f8.read()
        nonoLog = f9.read()
        decimoLog = f10.read()
        decimoprimeiroLog= f11.read()

    # Concatenar os logs
    merged_content = primeiroLog + segundoLog + terceiroLog + quartoLog + quintoLog + sextoLog + setimoLog + oitavoLog + nonoLog + decimoLog + decimoprimeiroLog

    # Mergear os logs em um novo
    new_file = input("Coloque o nome do novo arquivo: ")
    with open(new_file, 'wb') as new_f:
        new_f.write(merged_content)

    print("Você mergeou com sucesso!")
    print("Deseja ver o novo arquivo ? (s / n): ")

    check = input()
    if check == 'n':
        exit()
    else:
        print()
        c = open(new_file, "r")
        print(c.read())
        c.close()
```

Trying to make this work, but with some troubles :(

Comment: Just a reminder, I have 20 more logs in addition to the ones there

Comment: Iterate through archive members (possibly doing some filtering).